# Do I need to close my Redis connection?

Tags: redis, socket.io-redis

Using [ioredis](https://github.com/luin/ioredis). I'm not using the `redis.disconnect()` but recently I got a: `Ready check failed: ERR max number of clients reached` error.

Does this has to do with me not closing?

Comment: it's quite likely...

Comment: That's what I though, the thing though, is that if I do this, it closes the connection of my nodejs session.

Answer (score 1):

Use redisFree() to release connection socket created by redisConnect()

Continuously opening connections without closing is not a good practice. This will not only consume your resources but may also lead to program crash.
The maximum number of file descriptors that you can open simultaneously is 1024. If you exceed this limit Redis will show an error: can't create socket; too many open files.

Hope this will help..

Comment: What did you mean by redisFree()?